# message -"could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence"

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, postman

My problem is as follows: When i create POST request in "Postman" app. This is what i try to POST

```
  {"name": "John Doe", "email":"jdoe@test.com", "city": "London"}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-11-19T20:16:00.486+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence",
"path": "/api/ver01/product"
}
```

I was looking for answer in search box but none of them helped me. So i think that the problem is in sql code but I am not sure. Whole project is written in intelliJ IDE.

This is my Product class.

```
package com.hubertkulas.webstore.store.archetype;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Date;

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private boolean contact;
private String email;
private String category;
private String name;
private String city;

private String model;
private BigDecimal price;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
private Date date;



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public boolean isContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(boolean contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

// setter for id because Jackson will use it
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

This is my ProductController class

```
package com.hubertkulas.webstore.store.controllers;
import com.hubertkulas.webstore.store.archetype.Product;
import com.hubertkulas.webstore.store.jparepository.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/ver01/product")
public class ProductController {

//injecting ProductRepository when ProductController is called
@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;

@GetMapping
public List<Product> list() {
    //finds all of the records and returns it
   return productRepository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void create(@RequestBody Product product){
    productRepository.save(product);
}



@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Product get(@PathVariable("id") long id){
    // return specific record with added id
    return productRepository.getOne(id);
}

}
```

This is my ProductRepository Interface

```
package com.hubertkulas.webstore.store.jparepository;

import com.hubertkulas.webstore.store.archetype.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

//Using Jpa for CRUD operations
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

And this is my database

```
CREATE TABLE
product
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    contact BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR,
    category VARCHAR,
    name VARCHAR,
    city VARCHAR,
    date DATETIME,
    price NUMERIC,
    model VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE
hibernate_sequence
(
    next_val BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO product (id, contact, email, category, name, city, date, price)
VALUES (1, 1, 'abraham@site.com', 'Electronics', 'Abraham Westbrom', 'New 
York', 4419619200000, '3250');
INSERT INTO product (id, contact, email, category, name, city, date, price)
VALUES (2, 1, 'udon@site.com', 'Electronics', 'Udon Hon', 'London', 
4419619200000, '799');
INSERT INTO product (id, contact, email, category, name, city, date, price)
VALUES (3, 0, 'mateuszsinus@site.com', 'Software', 'Mateusz Sinus', 
'Warsaw', 4419619200000, '10000');

INSERT INTO hibernate_sequence (next_val) VALUES (4);
```

Comment: Please take a look in this post: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/getting-generate-could-not-read-a-hi-value-java-sql-sqlexception-invalid-object-name-hibernate_unique_key-sqlexception-error-192873336.html Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hibernate_sequence` table is wrong.

See [2.6.10. Using identifier table](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-table):

> ```
> create table hibernate_sequences(
>     sequence_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>     next_val INTEGER NOT NULL
> )
> ```

Comment: I have added 'NOT NULL' to my 'next_val BIGINT'. It solved this problem thank you very much.

Answer (score 13):

If you are creating a schema using spring boot for local database and jpa is configured to do a auto create-drop, ideally you wont be facing this situation.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

But in staging/production you want to handle your schema definition (DDL) separately so hibernate_sequence needs to have an initial value and 0 should suffice for start. It tells the program library from which number to start the auto-generation id.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

INSERT INTO <schema_name>.hibernate_sequence (next_val) VALUES (0);
```

The above one works for MYSQL

Comment: Using the INSERT command only fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
spring:
jpa:hibernate:ddl-auto: create-drop
```

in your application.yml file or application.properties file 
Do this only when you have truncated table or else you can add `INSERT INTO <schema_name>.hibernate_sequence (next_val) VALUES (1);`

Answer (score 1):

drop the table and re-create with next_val as primary key

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem. But I solved it by changing the generation strategy from AUTO to IDENTITY.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```